Start JSON server with JSON server Auth as middleware not working/running
I am trying to start json-server with json-server-auth as middleware with this command,
json-server data/db.json -m ./node_modules/json-server-auth --port 8000

as mentioned in their official documentation. I am getting this error,
\{^_^}/ hi!

  Loading data/db.json
  Loading ./node_modules/json-server-auth
Error: Cannot find module 'json-server'
Require stack:
- G:\learn-nest\node_modules\json-server-auth\dist\guards.js
- G:\learn-nest\node_modules\json-server-auth\dist\index.js
- C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\lib\cli\run.js
- C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\lib\cli\bin.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1142:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:983:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1230:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)       
    at Object.<anonymous> (G:\learn-nest\node_modules\json-server-auth\dist\guards.js:6:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1368:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1426:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1021:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1230:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'G:\\learn-nest\\node_modules\\json-server-auth\\dist\\guards.js',
    'G:\\learn-nest\\node_modules\\json-server-auth\\dist\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\json-server\\lib\\cli\\run.js',
    'C:\\Users\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\json-server\\lib\\cli\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\json-server\\lib\\cli\\bin.js'
  ]
}  

I have tried installing both json-server and json-server-auth as globally and locally. but when I run only json-server with this command,
json-server --watch data/db.json --port 8000

json-server is start and running as expected. But json-server with json-server-auth as middleware is not running. I am using the following versions json-server@1.0.0-alpha.23 and json-server-auth@2.1.0

"json-server@1.0.0-alpha.23", this version doesn't run with json-server-auth as middleware. But with "json-server@0.17.4" is running as expected with json-server-auth as middleware.
